# Updating the relative time in android

Tags: android, time, relative-date

I am developing a Twitter client application. As with other twitter clients, I would like to display the relative time of tweet with respect to the current time. I am using a list view and a Simple adapter that binds to an arraylist which stores the tweet information. If I calculate the relative time and store a string, I will be just storing static data which will never get updated. How should I update this data?? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to incorporate on your adapter a recalculation every X seconds. And if you update your adapter, the listview will update itself too.